# JSP form selection tag, display inner list

Tags: forms, jsp, taglib

My class is as follows

```
public class CriteriaConfigImpl implements CriteriaConfig {

    private long elementId;
    private String displayName;
    private String dataType;
    private String internalMap;
    private int displayOrder;
    private List<OperandType> operands;

    //..Setter Getter..//
}
```

And my main class is

```
public class Query {
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 0, max = 1500)
    private String queryString;

    private String searchFilterCondition;

    private List<CriteriaConfig> configuredCriteriaList;

    //.. Other operations ..//

}
```

On my JSP page I want to display the operands as a list, currently I have done as

```
<form:select path="searchFilterCondition" multiple="false">
                        <form:options items="${query.configuredCriteriaList}" itemLabel="operands" value="operands"/>
                    </form:select>
```

If my CriteriaConfig's are defined as

```
1. CriteriaConfig {1, "Test1", "String", "Test1", 1, "AND, OR, NOT" }
2. CriteriaConfig {2, "Trial", "Date", "Trial", 2, "LESSTHAN, GREATERTHAN" }
```

Now I want to check what displayName was selected and display the respective drop down, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thought I have a solution, but it will cause performance problems on the long run, in a case when I have more number of CriteriaConfig objects, but nevertheless, this is what I have now, unless someone comes up with a better soln.

```
<c:forEach items="${query.configuredCriteriaList}" var="queryOperations" varStatus="loopStatus">
                        <c:out value="${loopStatus.count}"/>
                        <c:out value="${queryOperations.displayName}"/>
                        <!-- If we want to display the operands specific for a display type, then we need the condition else, we can ignore it -->
                        <c:if test="${queryOperations.displayName=='Test1'}">
                            <form:select path="searchFilterCondition" multiple="false">
                                <form:options items="${queryOperations.operands}"  value="${queryOperations.operands}" itemLabel="operandType"/>
                            </form:select>
                        </c:if>
                    </c:forEach>
```